# Extract useful information from pandas df to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data coming for samples and each dataframe look like below.
I wish to convert extraction of each dataframe to a dictionary.

```
lake = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['t0', 't1', 't2', 't3'],
                 'area': [10, 20, 10, 15],
                 'freq': [100, 88, 130, 140],
                 'sensor1_avg': [2, 5, 2, 8],
                 'sensor2_avg': [3, 3, 2, 3],
                 'sensor3_avg': [7, 5, 2, 3],
                 'sensor4_avg': [7, 5, 2, 3]})

def process_df_todict(df):
    max_area = max(df.area)
    min_area = min(df.area)
    max_freq = max(df.freq)
    min_freq = min(df.freq)
    max_delta_sensor_avg = max(max(df.sensor1_avg)-min(df.sensor1_avg), max(df.sensor2_avg)-min(df.sensor2_avg), max(df.sensor3_avg)-min(df.sensor3_avg), max(df.sensor4_avg)-min(df.sensor4_avg))
    min_delta_sensor_avg = min(max(df.sensor1_avg)-min(df.sensor1_avg), max(df.sensor2_avg)-min(df.sensor2_avg), max(df.sensor3_avg)-min(df.sensor3_avg), max(df.sensor4_avg)-min(df.sensor4_avg))
    final_dict = {max_area : eval(max_area), min_area  : eval(min_area), ....}
    return final_dict

process_df_to_dict(lake)
```

> output: {'max_area': 20, 'min_area': 10, 'max_freq': 140, 'min_freq':
> 88, 'max_delta_sensor_avg':6, 'min_delta_sensor_avg':1}

Is there any better way to extract data out of dataframe to a dict than what is shown..?

Answer (score 1):

Column has built in `max` / `min` methods you can use, also no need for `eval`:

```
max_area = df.area.max()
```

For sensor columns summary, instead of enumerate all columns manually, you can use `filter(like='sensor')` and process all columns in one go:

```
lake.filter(like='sensor').pipe(
    lambda sensors: sensors.max() - sensors.min()
).pipe(
    lambda delta: {
        'max_delta_sensor_avg': delta.max(),
        'min_delta_sensor_avg': delta.min()
    }
)
{'max_delta_sensor_avg': 6, 'min_delta_sensor_avg': 1}
```

---

Put together:

```
def process_df_todict(df):
    sensor_stats = lake.filter(like='sensor').pipe(
        lambda sensors: sensors.max() - sensors.min()
    ).pipe(
        lambda delta: {'max_delta_sensor_avg': delta.max(), 'min_delta_sensor_avg': delta.min()}
    )
    return {
        'max_area': df.area.max(),
        'min_area': df.area.min(),
        'max_freq': df.freq.max(),
        'min_freq': df.freq.min(),
        **sensor_stats
    }

process_df_todict(lake)
{'max_area': 20, 'min_area': 10, 'max_freq': 140, 'min_freq': 88, 'max_delta_sensor_avg': 6, 'min_delta_sensor_avg': 1}
```